# Replace matrix product by power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $n$ diagonal matrices $D_i$ and a square matrix $A$, is it possible do find some matrix $D$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^n D_iA = (DA)^n$, or at least minimizes the difference between those two terms?

Comment: Do you want a $D$ that depends on $A$?

Comment: No. But if it helps, you could assume it does. I guess $D$ would depend on $D_i$ somehow

Comment: This is obviously possible when $D_i$ commutes with $A$ for every $i\ge2$ and our matrices are viewed as having entries in $\mathbb C$ or some other field in which every element has an $n$th root.  It's not possible to get equality even when the matrices are 1 by 1 if $n=2$, $D_1 A D_2 A = -1$ and we need $D$ and $A$ to have entries in $\mathbb R$.  Can you add additional conditions in the problem statement?